# Users cant see image on index in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Friends,on the index page there is image for each tittle but these are not show.

this is web site : `www.manisaihtiyac.com`

I think there is a problem right this code :

```
<div class="yef_resim">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <img src="<?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'logo', true); ?>" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what `logo` meta is returning? Do a var_dump like so on the page. `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'logo', true));` I think you have no value against `logo` meta in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is being returned by your function get_post_meta:

```
<a href="http://www.manisaihtiyac.com/?p=35">
<img src="" border="0">
...
```